# What will be the best framework to be used while automating an application build on extjs which will generate dynamic names and IDS?

Tags: selenium, extjs

What will be the best framework to be used while automating an application build on extjs which will generate dynamic names and IDS?

Using selenium and absolute xpath will be a good idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read how to ask questions in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Selenium` with `Protractor`, good to work with not, extJs application. .